# Displaying thumbnail preview of a document

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, xslt-list-view-web-part

I have an xslt list view webpart where I am displaying all the documents in a list. I want to implement on functionality where if user hover on a document link then I should display a small popup with top 50 characters from the document. Is it possible in SharePoint 2010. If yes, then how can I go for it?

It's like reading a document and fetching first 50 characters from there and displaying them in a popup. I can use jQuery for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a codeplex project titled Thumbnail Extender for SharePoint - the url is http://thumbextsp.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Home%20English.

It uses Office Web Apps to achieve the thumbnail preview. It doesn't support all document types but it works and is free.

[Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/6e838ee1-6840-40af-baf2-c72ed2d2c536/how-to-display-word-documents-in-the-thumbnail-view-in-document-library)